# CONTAINSTABLE does not work on single character

Tags: sql, sql-server, freetext, containstable

I am doing search using containstable() on a table but it is not working if I enter only single character in search string.
Below is the query I am using.

```
DECLARE @FreeTextSearch VARCHAR(500)='a'

SELECT tblProjectIDs.[KEY]
    FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Project,*,@FreeTextSearch)AS tblProjectIDs
```

I have project with name 'a'(ProjectName column) and Project leader with name 'ab'(ProjectLeader column).

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FreeTextSearch VARCHAR(500) = 'a'
SELECT tblProjectIDs.[KEY]
FROM dbo.tblProjectIDs
WHERE CONTAINS(*, @FreeTextSearch) OR ProjectName LIKE @FreeTextSearch
```

Comment: CONTAINS and CONTAINSTABLE both are different things. How can I solve this using CONTAINSTABLE function.?